# load fetched and filtered json from htm5 localstorage

Tags: reactjs, local-storage, fetch-api, use-effect, use-state

I try to fetch json from`https://api.github.com/users/moonhighway` and replace it and store in browser,and then load the new data from local storage but it doese not work.I am 100% inspired by this project:https://codesandbox.io/s/ancient-surf-730m1?file=/src/App.js
Below is my code:

```
const { useEffect, useState } = React;
const loadjson = (key) => JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem(key));
const savejson = (key, data) => {
  window.localStorage.setItem(JSON.stringify(key), JSON.stringify(data));
};
const App = ({ login }) => {
  const [data, setData] = useState(loadjson(`user:${login}`));

   useEffect(() => {
     if(!data) return;
     if (!`user:${login}`) return;
     if(data.login===login) return;
    const { name, avatar_url, location } = data;
    savejson(`user:${login}`, { name, avatar_url, location, login });
  },[data]);
  useEffect(() => {
    if (!login) return;
    if(data&&data.login===login) return;
    fetch(`https://api.github.com/users/${login}`)
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then(setData)
      .catch(console.error);
  },[login]);
 

  return <pre>{JSON.stringify(data, null, 2)}</pre>;

};
```

ReactDOM.render(, document.body);

my project link:https://codepen.io/nutkin/pen/QWKoabm?editors=1111,but it does not work.expected output looks like this:

```
{
  "name": "Moon Highway",
  "login": "moonhighway",
  "avatar_url": "https://avatars0.githubusercontent.com/u/5952087?v=4",
  "location": "Tahoe City, CA"
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because your save_key and load_key is different.

Please change your savejson like the following:

```
const savejson = (key, data) => {
  window.localStorage.setItem(key, JSON.stringify(data));
};
```